# Not spamming right amount of sprites

Tags: python, pygame

I want to spam four of these sprites , but only one spams.

```
def create_lives(hearts, all_sprites):

    corazon = Heart()

    for heart_number in range(1,4):
        corazon.x = (corazon.rect.width * heart_number)- corazon.rect.width
        corazon.rect.x = corazon.x
        corazon.rect.y = 40
        hearts.add(corazon)
        all_sprites.add(corazon)
```

This is my main loop:

```
def run_game(): 

    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    score = 0
    gf.create_lives(hearts, all_sprites)
    gf.add_mobs(ai_settings, all_sprites, mobs, meteor_imgs)


    while True:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, all_sprites, background, background_rect, hearts) 
        gf.check_events(player, all_sprites, bullets)   
        score = gf.collisions(score, screen, player, mobs, bullets, ai_settings, all_sprites, meteor_imgs)  
        gf.collisions(score, screen, player, mobs, bullets, ai_settings, all_sprites, meteor_imgs)  
        gf.draw_text(screen, "SCORE: " + str(score) , 20, 0,0, ai_settings)
        gf.draw_text(screen, "LIFE: " + str(player.shield) , 20, 0,20, ai_settings)
        all_sprites.update()        


        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

I though that looping through that range would result in 4 sprites being spammed.

Comment: Python isn't an "implicit copies everywhere" language like C++. `all_sprites.add(corazon)` doesn't copy `corazon`.

Comment: The term is spawn. Not spam.

Comment: @DanD. oops sorry english is not my first language and ive heard people saying that term but i thought they said "spam" thanks for clearing that out

Comment: That is why I said something rather than simply editing the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `corazon = Heart()` inside the for loop.